# How to remove CSS style tags from strings in SQL Server

Tags: html, css, sql-server, tags, styles

Need help in removing the CSS Style tags located outside of '<>' in my SQL Server extract. Below is a sample extract.

```
<HTML>
       <HEAD>
          <META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
          <STYLE type=text/css>P {   MARGIN: 0px  }  </STYLE>
       </HEAD>
       <BODY dir=ltr   style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; COLOR: #000000; FONT-FAMILY: Segoe UI">
          <SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 11pt; COLOR: black">
             <FONT   face="Times New Roman">
                <P style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt;">Actual text shows here.</P>
                <P style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt;"><B   ><FONT   size=2>&nbsp;</FONT></B></P>
                <P style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt">
             </FONT>
          </SPAN>
          </P>
       </BODY>
</HTML>
```

And here is the result after using a function that strips HTML tags from strings.

```
P { MARGIN: 0px }
```

Actual text shows here.

Kindly take note of `'P { MARGIN: 0px }'` that still continue to appear after using a function that strips HTML tags from strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try a replace function in SQL, just replace the occurrences of  with P { MARGIN: 0px }